# How to add value base on specific character ,also fix with certain digits in R

Tags: r

**There is the basic width : xxxx.xxxxxx (4digits before "." 6 digits after".")**

1. Have to add "0" when each side before and after "." is not enough digits.
2. Use regexr find "[.]" location with combination of str_pad can 
   fix the first 4 digits but
   don't know how to add value after the specific character with fixed digits.
   (cannot find a library can count the location **from somewhere specified**)

   Data like this

   ```
   > df
            Category
   1       300.030340
   2      3400.040290
   3        700.07011
   4        1700.0901
   5       700.070114
   6         700.0791
   7       3600.05059
   8        4400.0402
   ```

   Desired data

   ```
   > df
            Category
   1      0300.030340
   2      3400.040290
   3      0700.070110
   4      1700.090100
   5      0700.070114
   6      0700.079100
   7      3600.050590
   8      4400.040200
   ```

   I am beginner of coding that sometime can't understand some regex like "[" 
   e.t.c .With some explain of them would be super helpful.

   Also i have a combination like this :

   ```
   df$Category<-ifelse(regexpr("[.]",df$Category)==4,
                paste("0",df1$Category,sep = ""),df$Category)

   df$Category<-str_pad(df$Category,11,side = c("right"),pad="0")
   ```

Desire to know are there is any better way do this , especially count and 
return the location from the END until specific character appear.

Answer (score 3):

Using `formatC`:

```
df$Category <- formatC(as.numeric(df$Category), format = 'f', width = 11, flag = '0', digits = 6)
# > df
#      Category
# 1 0300.030340
# 2 3400.040290
# 3 0700.070110
# 4 1700.090100
# 5 0700.070114
# 6 0700.079100
# 7 3600.050590
# 8 4400.040200
```

- `format = 'f'`: formating doubles;
- `width = 11`: 4 digits before `.`  + 1 `.` + 6 digits after `.`;
- `flag = '0'`: pads leading zeros;
- `digits = 6`: the desired number of digits after the decimal point (format = "f");

Input `df` seems to be character data.frame:

```
structure(list(Category = c("300.030340", "3400.040290", "700.07011", 
"1700.0901", "700.070114", "700.0791", "3600.05059", "4400.0402"
)), .Names = "Category", row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Perfect. Gives the OP what they need, not necessarily what they ask for :)

Comment: Thank you . It is perfect. I should define the types of value for deciding a right function to be apply. Number as numeric method , Character as character method.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sprintf`

```
df$Category <- sprintf("%011.6f", df$Category)
df
#    Category
#1 0300.030340
#2 3400.040290
#3 0700.070110
#4 1700.090100
#5 0700.070114
#6 0700.079100
#7 3600.050590
#8 4400.040200
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Category = c(300.03034, 3400.04029, 700.07011, 
1700.0901, 700.070114, 700.0791, 3600.05059, 4400.0402)), 
.Names =   "Category", class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Comment: Can you confirm that this actually works? It doesn't work me (no leading zeros), and I don't understand why. Did `sprintf` change in recent R?

Comment: Thanks @akrun. The key was your change `%04.6f` to `%011.6f`. So `sprintf` works +1.

Comment: Thankyou akrun!  But "invalid format '%04.6f'; use format %s for character objects" turns out , once use as.numeric change in advance , the last "0" disappear this time.

Comment: @MauritsEvers  Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of great tricks, functions, and shortcuts to be learned, and I would encourage you to explore them all! For example, if you're trying to win [code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf), you will want to use @akrun's `sprintf()` approach. Since you stated you're a beginner, it might be more helpful to breakdown the problem into its component parts. One transparent and easy-to-follow, in my opinion, approach would be to utilize the `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)

location_of_dot <- str_locate(df$Category, "\\.")[, 1]
substring_left_of_dot <- str_sub(df$Category, end = location_of_dot - 1)
substring_right_of_dot <- str_sub(df$Category, start = location_of_dot + 1)

pad_left <- str_pad(substring_left_of_dot, 4, side = "left", pad = "0")
pad_right <- str_pad(substring_right_of_dot, 6, side = "right", pad = "0")

result <- paste0(pad_left, ".", pad_right)
result
```

Comment: Thankyou very much! It is a very easy to understand like using excel approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use `separate` in `tidyr` to separate `Category` on decimal. Use `str_pad` from `stringr` to add zeros in the front or back and paste them together.

```
library(tidyr) # to separate columns on decimal
library(dplyr) # to mutate and pipes
library(stringr) # to strpad
input_data <- read.table(text ="        Category
1       300.030340
2      3400.040290
3        700.07011
4        1700.0901
5       700.070114
6         700.0791
7       3600.05059
8        4400.0402", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  separate(Category, into = c("col1", "col2")) %>%
  mutate(col1 = str_pad(col1, width = 4, side= "left", pad  ="0"),
         col2 = str_pad(col2, width = 6, side= "right", pad  ="0"),
         Category = paste(col1, col2, sep = ".")) %>%
  select(-col1, -col2)
```

Comment: Thank you ! Very complete method with using simple method and mixed up.